# Clear Google Maps search history without removing the cached maps?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-maps, cache, search-history

I've been using the Google Maps app to cache the maps on certain places where I might be going in the future. I don't always have internet access which is why I'm doing this. Now that I've cached most of the places I might possibly go to, I want to clear my search history to remove the clutter. I don't want to clear the whole shebang. Otherwise, my "pre-caching" actions would just be wasted efforts. I just want the search history on Google Maps to be cleared. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that if you use the [Download Map lab](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/download-map-area-added-to-labs-in.html), you'll be able to clear your cache (but not data) without also clearing the maps. But you can't do directions or search with those maps.

In reality I think you'd probably be better off downloading an app specifically made for offline maps access, such as [MapDroyd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osa.android.mapdroyd&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5vc2EuYW5kcm9pZC5tYXBkcm95ZCJd).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can clear the location history.

For that open settings > Location > Location Services > Google Location History.
Here you will see the Delete location history option at the bottom of screen.

Just hit that option.

That's it !!